# My label is being included as a feature when I create a pytorch model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, tensor, feature-selection

I have started to create a pytorch model but for some reason my label ('Price_Night') is being included in my features tensor. This is my code

```
class AirbnbNightlyPriceImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.data = pd.read_csv('tabular_data/clean_tabular_data.csv')
        self.features, self.label = load_airbnb(self.data, 'Price_Night')

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        features = self.features[idx,:]
        features = torch.tensor(features, dtype=torch.float32)
        label = self.label[idx].item()
        return (features, label)
 

dataset = AirbnbNightlyPriceImageDataset()

# split dataset into training, validation & test sets
train_set, test_set = random_split(dataset, [int(len(dataset) * 0.7), len(dataset) - int(len(dataset) * 0.7)])
test_set, validation_set = random_split(test_set, [int(len(test_set) * 0.5), len(test_set) - int(len(test_set) * 0.5)])

# create dataloaders for each set
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(validation_set, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_set, batch_size=8, shuffle=True)

example = next(iter(train_loader))
print(example)
```

And when I print(example), I get this output

```
[tensor([[  2.0000,   1.0000,   1.0000,  49.0000,   4.8000,   4.9000,   5.0000,
           4.9000,   5.0000,   4.8000,  17.0000,   1.0000],
        [  4.0000,   2.0000,   1.0000, 231.0000,   4.9000,   5.0000,   5.0000,
           5.0000,   5.0000,   4.8000,  64.0000,   2.0000],]]), tensor([ 49, 231])]
```

As you can see the first label (49) is also included as a feature. I need them to be separate but not sure how I can acheive this.

Comment: You have to split them up / unpack them: `data, label = next(iter(train_loader))`

Comment: I figured out the issue was with my load_airbnb function I defined in another file. Thanks for the help anaway @Daraan!